# Compile RocksDB to Native in Quarkus

Tags: native, quarkus, rocksdb

n my application, I am using RocksDB. I would compile this application natively. However, I have this error:
{"refId":1,"exceptionType":"java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError","message":"org.rocksdb.DBOptions.newDBOptions()J [symbol: Java_org_rocksdb_DBOptions_newDBOptions or Java_org_rocksdb_DBOptions_newDBOptions__]","frames":[{"class":"com.oracle.svm.core.jni.access.JNINativeLinkage","method":"getOrFindEntryPoint","line":152},{"class":"com.oracle.svm.core.jni.JNIGeneratedMethodSupport","method":"nativeCallAddress","line":53},{"class":"org.rocksdb.DBOptions","method":"newDBOptions"}...
How can I solve this problem?

I know that the RocksDB library is not native but I think it is possible to compile because Kafka Stream uses RocksDB as well.

Answer (score 0):

You would need a dedicated rocksdb extension that essentially does what Quarkus does [here](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/3.2.0.Final/extensions/kafka-streams/deployment/src/main/java/io/quarkus/kafka/streams/deployment/KafkaStreamsProcessor.java#L142) and [here](https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/blob/3.2.0.Final/extensions/kafka-streams/deployment/src/main/java/io/quarkus/kafka/streams/deployment/KafkaStreamsProcessor.java#L154)